# Cast List<object> to List<myclass> c#

Tags: c#, linq, devexpress

By this code I got list of selected rows in AspxGrid.

```
string[] fieldName = new string[] { "UserId", "Name", "Address" };
List<object> SelectedList = Grid.GetSelectedFieldValues(fieldName);
```

Now I want to perform one of the below operation.

1. Filter this List of object by userid where userid = 1 using linq
2. Cast this `List<object>` into `List<Users>`

I have tried following two methods but Exception occurs.

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type
>   'CubeDataObject.Claims'.

```
List<Users> mylist = (List<Users>)(Object)SelectedList;
List<Users> listd = SelectedList.Select(n => (Users)n).ToList();
```

I have also tried so many other methods too but tired.

Comment: Where are you getting the exception?

Comment: Firstly thanks for quick reply. Its occurs when I uses this method.
List<Users> listd = SelectedList.Select(n => (Users)n).ToList();

Comment: I am afraid why some guys are down voted my Question. :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that you have list of boxed `object[]`. So, you need to unbox it and get the values of `UserId`, `Name`, `Address` by its corresponding index.
Here is example:

```
List<Users> mylist = SelectedList
    .Where(item => (int)((object[])item)[0] == 1)
    .Select(item =>
    {
        var values = (object[])item;

        return new Users()
        {
            UserId = (int)values[0],
            Name = (string)values[1],
            Address = (string)values[2]
        };
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Worked perfect. :) Bundle of Thanks @nempoBu4

Answer (score 9):

For this simple tast the [`Cast`-extension-method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx) on `Enumerable` exists:

```
var myList = SelectedList.Cast<User>();
```

Now you can easily filter:

```
var result = myList.Where(x => x.userId == 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Linq has a special method for casting lists:

```
List<Users> mylist = SelectedList.Cast<Users>().Where(u => u.userid == 1).ToList();
```

This should work, assuming the objects are actually castable to a Users object.

Comment: Exception
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type 'Users'.

Comment: In that case your objects are not of type user. Take a look at nempobu4's solution.